# How do you search object for a property within property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search

I have this object:

```
key = {
    spawn:{type:1,img:app.assets.get('assets/spawn.svg')},
    wall:{type:2,img:app.assets.get('assets/wall.svg')},   
    grass:{type:3,img:app.assets.get('assets/grass.svg')},
    spike:{type:4,img:app.assets.get('assets/spike.svg')},
    ground:{type:5,img:app.assets.get('assets/ground.svg')}
  };
```

And I have an array with only types and I need to add the given image to it, the array looks something like this:

```
[{type:1,image:null},{type:3,image:null},{type:2,image:null},{type:2,image:null},{type:5,image:null}]
```

Basically I want to loop the array, find the type in the key object and get the given image and save it into the array.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? We tend only to help with existing code, not write it all for you.

Comment: I don't feel like putting this together right now, but it's a lodash one-liner for the enthusiastic.

Comment: This is actually a good question and deserves upvotes, especially if it gets a good answer (the existing answers are not modern Javascript). I'll be bountying it soon.

Comment: @Andy problem is that oftentimes good answers are very hard to find from guessy attempts. Code attempts usually helps to clarify what one is actually trying to do, but I think the code is clear enough given the compilable input and output.

Comment: @djechlin, that object and that array could have come from anywhere and the OP showed no attempt at trying to solve the problem themselves. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @Andy http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179038/183887 for some background on the purpose of requiring research effort. I do think both that the OP's articulation constitutes research effort, and that regardless it fulfills the purposes of research effort. Your comment "SO is not a coding service" does not seem relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that stands out here for me is the line

> ...get the given image and save it into the array

I'm assuming this means the original array. I think a better approach would be to map the appropriate keys and values to a new array but I've assumed, for this example, that it's a requirement.

In an attempt to keep the solution as terse as possible and the request for a lodash solution:

```
_.each(key, function(prop){
    _.each(_.filter(types, { type: prop.type }), function(type) { type.image = prop.img });
});
```

Comment: Enjoy reaching 1000 rep :)

Answer (score 2):

Given the object of keys and an array of objects like so:

```
var key = {
    spawn:{type:1,img:app.assets.get('assets/spawn.svg')},
    wall:{type:2,img:app.assets.get('assets/wall.svg')},   
    grass:{type:3,img:app.assets.get('assets/grass.svg')},
    spike:{type:4,img:app.assets.get('assets/spike.svg')},
    ground:{type:5,img:app.assets.get('assets/ground.svg')}
};
var arr = [{type:1,image:null},{type:3,image:null},{type:2,image:null},{type:2,image:null},{type:5,image:null}];
```

We can first create an array of the properties in the object `key` to make iterating it simpler.
Then loop over the array `arr`, and upon each member, check with a [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) loop which image belongs to the member by its type (some returning on the first `true` and ending the loop).

You can change the `forEach` to a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (and assign the returned new array to `arr` or a new variable) if you want the loop to be without side-effects, and not to mutate the original array.

```
var keyTypes = Object.keys(key);
arr.forEach(function (item) {
    keyTypes.some(function (keyType) {
        if (key[keyType].type === item.type) {
            item.image = key[keyType].img;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

The smarter thing would be to change the object of the imagetypes so that you could use the type as the accessing property, or create another object for that (as pointed out in another answer).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this solution is modern, but it does not use any loops or recursion.

```
object = {
    spawn: {type:1, img:app.assets.get('assets/spawn.svg')},
    wall: {type:2, img:app.assets.get('assets/wall.svg')},   
    grass: {type:3, img:app.assets.get('assets/grass.svg')},
    spike: {type:4, img:app.assets.get('assets/spike.svg')},
    ground: {type:5, img:app.assets.get('assets/ground.svg')}
};
arr = [
    {type:1, image:null},
    {type:3, image:null},
    {type:2, image:null},
    {type:2, image:null},
    {type:5, image:null}
];

var typeImages = {};
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).forEach(function(value){
    typeImages[object[value].type] = object[value].img;
});
arr = arr.map(function(value){
    return {
        type: value.type,
        image: typeImages[value.type]
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var key = {
    spawn:{type:1,img:app.assets.get('assets/spawn.svg')},
    wall:{type:2,img:app.assets.get('assets/wall.svg')},   
    grass:{type:3,img:app.assets.get('assets/grass.svg')},
    spike:{type:4,img:app.assets.get('assets/spike.svg')},
    ground:{type:5,img:app.assets.get('assets/ground.svg')}
  };
var typesArray = [{type:1,image:null},{type:3,image:null},{type:2,image:null},{type:2,image:null},{type:5,image:null}];

for(var i = 0, j = typesArray.length; i < j; i++)
{
    typesArray[i].image = getKeyObjectFromType(typesArray[i].type).img;
}

function getKeyObjectFromType(type)
{
    for(var k in key)
    {
        if(key[k].type == type)
        {
            return key[k];
        }
    }
    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < typesArray.length; i++) {
    for (prop in key) {
        if (key[prop].type === typesArray[i].type) {
            typesArray[i].image = key[prop].img;
        }
    }
}
```

It loops through the array ("typesArray"), and for each array item, it go through all the objects in key looking for the one with the same "type". When it finds it, it takes that key object's "img" and saves into the array.

Comment: Please add some explanation on how this solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash (https://lodash.com/):

```
var key = {
    spawn:{type:1,img:app.assets.get('assets/spawn.svg')},
    wall:{type:2,img:app.assets.get('assets/wall.svg')},   
    grass:{type:3,img:app.assets.get('assets/grass.svg')},
    spike:{type:4,img:app.assets.get('assets/spike.svg')},
    ground:{type:5,img:app.assets.get('assets/ground.svg')}
};

var initialList = [{type:1,image:null},{type:3,image:null},{type:2,image:null},{type:2,image:null},{type:5,image:null}];

var updatedList = _.transform(initialList, function(result, item) {
    item.image = _.find(key, _.matchesProperty('type', item.type)).img;
    result.push(item);
});
```

This will go over every item in the `initialList`, find the object that matched their `type` property in `key` and put it in the `image` property.

The end result will be in `updatedList`

Comment: you can lodashly produce initial list. in general it's better to avoid updating objects in place, or to let the framework handle that,i.e. do things more immutably (this just occurred to me - I'm learning best practice right now too).